# What comic device is based on unexpected changes in meaning?

Tags: humor, literary-device

> To be a really good lover, then, one must be strong and yet tender. How strong? I suppose being able to lift fifty pounds should do it.

- Woody Allen

I am not asking specifically about the ludicrous lowering of the tone/importance of a word; I am asking about incongruously changing the meaning of a word or phrase in a latter sentence as pointed out in Jason’s answer.

Comment: The question that this was marked a duplicate of is something quite different.

Comment: Perhaps you should explicitly change the title of your question—something like: What comic device is based on unexpected changes in meaning?

Comment: @Jason Of course bathos is involved. And of course it's a paraprosdokian {[Is there a term for the type of misleading joke comedians such as Stephen Colber ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/426215/is-there-a-term-for-the-type-of-misleading-joke-comedians-such-as-stephen-colber/426241#426241)}. Both of these have duplicates.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I would wholeheartedly endorse marking this a duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/346013/wordplay-that-thwarts-expectation-by-applying-a-description-to-a-different-objec/346471#346471 That question really is the same.

Comment: Paraprosdokians almost always involve bathos, the switch in sense being zany and ludicrous.

Comment: The original, and most appropriate question that this should be a duplicate of is: [Is there a name for this type of sentence structure: “She looks as though she's been poured into her clothes, and forgot to say 'when'”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14949/is-there-a-name-for-this-type-of-sentence-structure-she-looks-as-though-shes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Paraprosdokian**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paraprosdokian):

> A paraprosdokian (/pærəprɒsˈdoʊkiən/) is a figure of speech in which
>   the latter part of a sentence, phrase, or larger discourse is
>   surprising or unexpected in a way that causes the reader or listener
>   to reframe or reinterpret the first part. It is frequently used for
>   humorous or dramatic effect, sometimes producing an anticlimax. For
>   this reason, it is extremely popular among comedians and satirists.
>   Some paraprosdokians not only change the meaning of an early phrase,
>   but they also play on the double meaning of a particular word,
>   creating a form of syllepsis.

In this case, when the word **strong** is read in the first sentence, it's taken in the sense of "steady" or "committed" (having emotional strength). It's only at the end of the joke that Allen switches its meaning to one of physical strength.

Groucho Marx had a famous example of this:

> One morning I shot an elephant in my pajamas. How he got into my pajamas I'll never know.

Note: I linked to the Wikipedia definition because its was the most extensive. Interestingly, the word doesn't have a definition in the online Merriam-Webster or Oxford dictionaries; nevertheless, Merriam-Webster *does* provide a definition in one of its [blog posts](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/internets-favorite-words/paraprosdokian). (It is obviously a "rare" word.)

Comment: Groucho's elephant and his penchant for paraprosdokians have been covered numerous times.